# Azure AD + MSAL Angular - Signing out from other apps does not sign out of angular app

Tags: angular, azure-ad-msal

Here is my scenario.  I have authenticated to our org's Azure AD.  I have two apps open in browser tabs: the Office 365 Portal and the sample Angular v16 MSAL application.  Both applications are showing as logged in and the Angular app can access the restricted routes.

If I select logout from the Angular app, it takes me to the Microsoft page that prompts for which account to logout and it completes the logout.  If I refresh the O365 Portal, I am logged out there as well.

But if I select logout from the O365 Portal and complete the account select, the Angular app remains logged in upon refresh.  It remains logged in even if the browser is closed.  If I select the Angular app's logout button, it will log out but it doesn't prompt for account selection.  I assume this is because on Microsoft's side, they think all the accounts are logged out.

My assumption is the default setup in the demo app isn't validating the stored tokens against AzureAD upon Init?  What is missing?  We are moving out apps to AzureAd and I don't want to have one app that has to be manually logged out of?